# ionic - How to wordwrap a long string in ion-header

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my code, and I tried `text-wrap` , inside `ion-header` still can not show whole title.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar text-wrap color="danger">
    <ion-buttons>
        <button ion-button navPop icon-only>
            <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-back" md="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{new.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]

Update

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="danger">
    <ion-buttons>
        <button ion-button navPop icon-only>
            <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-back" md="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-item color="danger" text-wrap>
     <ion-title >{{new.title}}</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I tried add `ion-item` there, but still not working for me.
[image]

Update 2

```
.ios .toolbar-title {
   text-overflow: inherit;
   white-space: normal;
   text-align: left;
   font-size:1.3em;
}

.md .toolbar-title {
   text-overflow: inherit;
   white-space: normal;
   text-align: left;
   font-size:1.3em;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Including such a long title seems like a bad design... Why don't you include that long title as a title but in the _body of the page_ instead?

Comment: This one work for someone, design not by myself. Thank you : )

Comment: @sebaferreras Why do you think that it is bad design? I just have to deal with this issue on a page, where I show a details of a contact. The title have the contacts full name, and some people do have long names. Is it a bad design to put a contacts full name as a page title?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pls update your css file as below :

```
.toolbar-title {
   text-overflow: inherit;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

**Edited:**

Or

```
.toolbar-title {
   text-overflow: unset;
   white-space: unset;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but why ios showing not good in my app..I update new code and image in my question

Comment: don't know why ios different with android @Mankeomorakort

Comment: Seems logic, but is not working for me. :(

Even using [text-wrap] attribute on ion-title, or inline style, or !important in .toolba-title. Seems been replaced with the original css

Comment: @Finesse: This solution should work only with ionic2

Answer (score 15):

A little neater than Finesse's answer (for Ionic 5):

```
<ion-title>
  <div class="ion-text-wrap">
    {{new.title}}
  </div>
</ion-title>
```

Comment: I have added class="ion-no-padding" to title and it is perfect

Answer (score 6):

Add an extra wrapper to your `<ion-title>` content to enable the wrapping:

```html
<ion-title>
  <div style="white-space: normal;">
    {{new.title}}
  </div>
</ion-title>
```

Additionally, if you want the title to extend the header when there is too much text, add the following CSS code:

```css
ion-title {
  position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick work around is to set `mode="md"` prop to `ion-title`.

```
<ion-title mode="md">{{new.title}}</ion-title>
```