# ionic 4 - How to wordwrap a long string in ion-header

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Good day all

I am busy building an app in the newly released version of Ionic, namely Ionic 4. I am struggling to do something that should be a fairly easy, but I am not having any luck.

I am trying to prevent my header title's from cutting off when they are too long to display in one line.

I have found several posts here that cover this topic, but none for Ionic 4 specifically. None of the solutions that seem to work for the older versions are solving my issue. Two of these are as follows:

[ionic - How to wordwrap a long string in ion-header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670752/ionic-how-to-wordwrap-a-long-string-in-ion-header)

[How to wordwrap a long string in ion-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335101/how-to-wordwrap-a-long-string-in-ion-item)

I would love to show you a fiddle o something similar to illustrate my problem further, but am also struggling to find an online tool that allows to do so with Ionic 4.

Is there anyone else who have perhaps solved this issue before? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use this Ionic 4 blank template on stackblitz: https://ionic-4-blank-template.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks @TomasVancoillie. I'll add one ins a minute!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to force text warp with Ionic 4 elements using a span inside the element and using the following CSS:

```
<ion-header>
<span class="wrap-text">Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious if you say it loud enough you'll always sound precocious</span>
</ion-header>

.wrap-text {
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: unset;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```